# Problema no redirecionamento da página pela rota

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Essa são as rotas

```
{
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Pacotes",
           url: "Passo/{name}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Passo", action = "Passo_01", name = "" }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "RotaConteudo",
           url: "Conteudo/{name}/{Parametro}/{tipo}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Conteudo", action = "Conteudo", name = "", Parametro = "", tipo = "" }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "RotaPasso_6",
           url: "Passo/{name}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Passo", action = "Passo_6", name = "" }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Na minha controller há duas ActionResult: Passo_01 e Passo_06.

Essa é a chamada na Index do Passo_06

```
<button id="btnGravarPassageiros" onclick="window.location.href='/Passo/Passo_06'" value="novaPesquisa" class="btn-pular-passo pull-right">Ir para o passo 06</button>
```

O que passa é que eu clico no botão para ir para o Passo_06, e ele me redireciona para o Passo_01. Se comento as rotas, funciona. O que mais devo fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `UrlHelper` para ajudar na criação de urls em sua view:

```
Url.Action("Passo_06", "Passo")
```

Exemplificando o uso:

```
<button
    id="btnGravarPassageiros"
    onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Passo_06", "Passo")'"
    value="novaPesquisa" class="btn-pular-passo pull-right">Ir para o passo 06</button>
```

Comment: Ok, amigo, continua vindo a Action Passo_01 e não a Passo_06. Fiz conforme exemplo.

Comment: O problema está em suas rotas. Você está usando a mesma url (`url: "Passo/{name}"`) tanto para a action `Passo_01` quanto para a action `Passo_06`. A url deveria ser diferente, algo do tipo `Passo/1/{name}` e `Passo/6/{name}`.

Comment: Cara, muuuuuito obrigado. Funcionou!!! Era isso mesmo. Mas uma para "boas práticas", ehehehehehe.

Comment: Você pode marcar esta resposta como sendo a solução do problema então! Assim, as pessoas saberão que está resolvida, além de eu ganhar uns pontinhos. =D

Comment: Como eu marco uma resposta?

Comment: Tem um sinal abaixo das setas para votar, parecido com um "✓", quando você clicar neste "✓" ele vai ficar preenchido de verde.